# GHC Install Without Root

Tags: haskell, installation, ghc

So I'd like to set up a linux machine for Haskell development with one huge caveat -- no root privs on this machine. We could of course get the admins to install GHC for us, eventually. However, in the long-term then we need to hassle them when we want to upgrade, etc. So much better to do everything in userland. Which also means that we'll want to install c libs we link to in userland as well, etc. to keep everything as hassle-free as possible.

So, the question is, how, soup-to-nuts, would I go about doing a purely userland install of GHC? The machine will have gcc, and the usual toolchain. If necessary, we can start with a typical ghc install to get the ball rolling, but it would be nice not to.

Additionally, any tips on managing an environment like this would be appreciated, especially involving how such a setup can be manageable with multiple devs/accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You obviously need a directory that all pertinent users have at least read permission on. Say /home/foo, with subdirectories bin, lib, share, .cabal. Then `./configure --prefix=/home/foo` and make && make install, and make sure that /home/foo/* is before /usr/* in everybody's PATH, LIBRARY_PATH etc. You should probably start with installing gcc and c-libs there, and when everything C is installed, install ghc.

Comment: In particular, you'll need to install a binary ghc distribution from http://haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_2_1#binaries, since you need ghc to bootstrap self-compilation.

Answer (score 6):

I did this too. I created a directory `~/usr` and passed `--prefix=$HOME/usr` to all configure scripts. Using the Haskell Platform makes this process even smoother.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install ghc through stack by [following these instructions](https://github.com/yantonov/install-ghc/blob/master/ubuntu/install-ghc-ubuntu.md). It worked like a charm; the only additional thing I had to do was to install [the GMP library](https://gmplib.org/) and to add it to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Are you sure this didn't require root permissions at some point? The standard ways to install Stack all do, AFAIK.

Comment: I do not have root permissions for the machine I installed this on, so yes, I am sure :-) The instructions I linked to just download a binary version of stack, and then stack simply downloads GHC and GHCI and places them into its ~/.stack directory.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, the linked instructions look like they install Stack in a user-specific directory.

Comment: Whooosh! How amazing is this! Somebody tie me down before I crash my Uni's supercomputer with Haskell programs I'm not supposed to run there...

Comment: I'm trying this but `ls -1 | grep 'stack-.*\.tar\.gz'` returns nothing and of course this leads to an error when using `tar xvf` on it. The directory only contains a file named `linux-x86_64`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use stack to install `ghc` or `ghci`, follow [this offical manual](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#manual-download_2):

1. download the `tar.gz` file from the release link (`curl`/`wget`/even `scp` can upload your local file to a remote server)
2. extract the file with `tar xvzf` and enter the folder test if `./stack` run properly
3. add

```
export PATH="<stack_path>:$PATH"
```

to `~/.bashrc`

Every time you start the terminal, do `source ~/.bashrc`

4. install `ghci` locally

```
stack ghci
```

It will install `ghci` automatically and launch it.